# How to find the center of the power series.

Tags: power-series

How to find the center of the power series.

$\sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 2n(x+1)^ n }{ 3^ n }  } $

I think it to be (x-(-1))= so, the center is -1

Comment: Yes, it is $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition a power series $\Sigma a_n(x-x_0)^n$ is centered at $x_0$. So in your problem it's indeed centered at -1